# store the results of sed to a variable

Tags: bash

I have the following code...it is mostly working. Except I am wanting to write the result of sed into the variable newData. Have viewed many other posts, and none have managed to work for me.

```
newin="<font color='default'>Default Color has been choosen.</font>"

newData="$newin" | sed 's/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g; s/<[^>]*>//g'

if [[ ${newin:0:1} == "<" ]]
then

    #this echo works like it should
    echo "$newin" | sed 's/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g; s/<[^>]*>//g'

    #this echo works like it should

    echo "$newin"

    #The variable newData does not seem to capture the data
    newData=${newin} | sed 's/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g; s/<[^>]*>//g'
    echo "[$newdata]"

fi
```

it outputs:

```
Default Color has been choosen.
<font color='default'>Default Color has been choosen.</font>
[]
```

Comment: Have you tried `newData=$(${newin} | sed 's/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g; s/<[^>]*>//g')`?

Comment: no luck using the $(${newin} ....approach

Comment: it would work with `newData=$(echo ${newin} | sed 's/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g; s/<[^>]*>//g')`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -- That works perfect. I wasn't even thinking along the lines of just wrapping the entire original command into it, but it works flawlessly. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. Good call on the echo.